# How to auto-rebuild bundle with webpack-dev-server without run command again?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, rebuild, webpack-4

I'm a newbie in webpack and I'm using webpack 4 for my project. But I have a problem, I have some file scripts. In the first time to build with webpack dev server, it's run okay. But when server running, I continue create a new file script(example: c.js), rename or delete the exist file  the server not auto build this script to main.js. How can automatic webpack rebuild my new file(c.js) to main.js without run command again?

**This is my repo on github:**
https://github.com/aiduc93/webpack4-scss-pug-es6

You can follow this step to reproduce my problem:

Step 1: start server with 'npm run dev' and run localhost:3000 in browser.

Step 2: when server running, we create new file(c.js), you can copy my code in hide.js or show.js and change the pluginName to 'anything'(ie: pluginName='clickable')

Step 3: go to index.pug, create new p tag with data-clickable(ie: p(data-clickable) clickable)

Step 4: refresh page in browser and click to text clickable. Js will not run because it not recompile.

**This is my structure**

```
//folder javascript in project
  javascript
     | hide.js
     | show.js
     | server.js
//folder dist after build
  dist
     | main.js
```

**This is script in package.json**

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot",
"build": "webpack --mode production"},
```

**This is webpack.config.js**

```html
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin')
module.exports = { 
  entry: { main: glob.sync('./src/**/*.js*')} ,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'main.js',
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  watch: true,
  
  module: {
    
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: ["html-loader", "pug-html-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]

      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
          {
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use:  [   'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
          })
      },
      {
        type: 'javascript/auto',
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: "./plugin-config/[name].[ext]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    inline: true,
    port: 3000,
    // historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin(
      { filename: 'style.css'}
    ),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin('dist', { watch: true,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: false,
      hash: true,
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
    new WebpackMd5Hash(),
  ]
};
```

Comment: How should webpack know what to do with `c.js` if you don't reference it anywhere? Adding a `*.js` is not enough..

Comment: Hi @Legends, so webpack just recompile when we reference it(c.js) anywhere? If i don't reference it, can we have another way webpack recompile it by automatic?

Comment: If you don't reference it, it will not be included. You have to be more clear, what do you mean by recompile? Do you want to tranform the file from a higher ECMA version to a lower like ES5?
And why do you need this file, if you do not reference it anywhere. What should `c.js` do?

Comment: Hi @Legends, with c.js, i will create a plugin jquery in this file, and using data attribute for trigger run this file.

Comment: I twould be good to create a little repo for this, so we can take a look at it

Comment: Hi @Legends, I edited my post. You can check my code in repo. I updated the step for you can reproduce my problem. Thanks!

Comment: This won't work, if you don't reference it (import) in `server.js`.
And the following is not wp4 compatible `entry: { main: glob.sync('./src/**/*.js*')}`. If `server.js` is your entrypoint, then `main` should point to `server.js` where you have to import `hide`, `show` and `clickable`. Only real entry-points are configured under `entry`, no other scripts like plugins, vendor scripts...

Comment: So, i must be add new file to the server.js when created new file. Is it right, sir? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In webpack 4 only real entry-points are entry-points, this means, no vendor-scripts, plugins...in entry.
You cannot use `glob` here beause it creates an array of all js-files and only `server.js` is your real entry-point for your application!

Adding a js-file to your wp project doesn't mean it will be compiled as you don't reference it anywhere, so wp cannot know that it is needed.
WP creates a dependency graph starting from the dependencies of your entry-point(s) and creates the bundle(s).

Your `server.js` is your entry-point and should look like this:

```
import "../stylesheets/style.scss";
import $ from 'jquery';
import "./clickable"  // without import no recompile!
import "./hide"
import "./show"

console.log("his");
console.log("hello, world23");
```

The entry-point in your `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
      main: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/javascripts/server.js")
      },
```

Comment: Sorry for reply too late, I fixed it follow your solution. Thanks so much!